# How to access a database from a broadcastreceiver (ReceiverRestrictedContext)?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, alarmmanager

I am trying to get some values from my app's sqlite database using the alarm manager.
now as we all know the DB class which extends SQLiteOpenHelper  requires a context, and the broadcastreceiver gets a context like this:

```
@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
```

the problem is that when I call the DB class with this context I get the following exception:

> Unable to start receiver com.ayham.mycar.AlarmBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext

the full code is like this:

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
NotificationManager nm; 
@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //get the values from the DB:
    DBhelper mDBGet=new DBhelper(context);
    Cursor mCursor=mDBGet.allProperties((Activity) context);}}
```

I know I'm not supposed to cast the context into an Activity but if I don't the compiler gives me an error.
how can I get this done?

Answer (score 1):

The Broadcast receivers are supposed to very light. So the best way to do it is to delegate it to an activity or a service ... and when you start and activity/Service, you can use **this** as the Context.

Comment: it didn't work now i get a NullpointerException for the context